# How to pass parameters into test script

Tags: truffle

I have a voting solidity file here:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
// We have to specify what version of compiler this code will compile with

contract Votingapp{
  /* mapping field below is equivalent to an associative array or hash.
  The key of the mapping is candidate name stored as type bytes32 and value is
  an unsigned integer to store the vote count
  */

  mapping (bytes32 => uint256) public votesReceived;

  /* Solidity doesn't let you pass in an array of strings in the constructor (yet).
  We will use an array of bytes32 instead to store the list of candidates
  */

  bytes32[] public candidateList;

  /* This is the constructor which will be called once when you
  deploy the contract to the blockchain. When we deploy the contract,
  we will pass an array of candidates who will be contesting in the election
  */
  constructor(bytes32[] memory candidateNames) public {
    candidateList = candidateNames;
  }

  // This function returns the total votes a candidate has received so far
  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint256) {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }

  // This function increments the vote count for the specified candidate. This
  // is equivalent to casting a vote
  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    votesReceived[candidate] += 1;
  }

  function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {
      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is my migration file 2_deploy.js

```
const Votingapp = artifacts.require("Votingapp");
listOfCandidates = ['Rama', 'Nick', 'Jose']
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Votingapp, listOfCandidates.map(name => web3.utils.asciiToHex(name)));
};
```

this is my js test script

```
var Votingapp = artifacts.require('Votingapp');
contract('Votingapp', function(accounts) {
  let instance;
  before(async () => {
    instance = await Votingapp.deployed();
  });
  it('check users in list',async () => {

    console.log("this is the" +  instance.candidateList.call());
    await instance.candidateList.call()

  });
});
```

However I keep getting a

```
  Contract: Votingapp
this is the[object Promise]
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "candidateList". Got 0 expected 1!
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "candidateList". Got 0 expected 1!
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:726
  err.uncaught = true;
               ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'uncaught' on string 'abort(Error: Invalid number of parameters for "candidateList". Got 0 expected 1!). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.'
    at Runner.uncaught (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:726:16)
    at process.uncaught (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:839:10)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:485:1)
```

Any help what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With the `bytes32[] public candidateList;` array in your contract, the compiler implicitly adds the following function to the contract:

```
function candidateList(uint index) public view returns (bytes32);
```

So your call to `instance.candidateList.call()` is obviously missing an input argument (`index`).

If you want to be able to get the entire array, then you need to implement that function yourself:

```
function getCandidateList() public view returns (bytes32[]) {
    return candidateList;
}
```